# API xStation xtb log in troubles

Tags: python-3.x, algorithmic-trading

Someone knows how to log in to xtb API ? http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/

Python request:

```
import requests, json

parameters = {
    "command" : "login",
    "arguments" : {
        "userId" : "10576375",
        "password": "PASSWORD"
    }
}

response = requests.get("https://xapia.x-station.eu:5124", params=parameters)
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Response :

> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It requires an SSL connection. Try the following (works for me):

```
import socket
import ssl
import json

host = 'xapia.x-station.eu'
port = 5124
USERID = 123456
PASSWORD = 'YOURPASSWORD'

host = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port)[0][4][0]

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))
s = ssl.wrap_socket(s)

parameters = {
    "command" : "login",
    "arguments" : {
        "userId": USERID,
        "password": PASSWORD
    }
}
packet = json.dumps(parameters, indent=4)
s.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))

END = b'\n\n'
response = s.recv(8192)
if END in response:
    print('Print login: {}'.format(response[:response.find(END)]))

parameters = {
    "command" : "logout"
}
packet = json.dumps(parameters, indent=4)
s.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))

response = s.recv(8192)
if END in response:
    print('Print logout: {}'.format(response[:response.find(END)]))
```

Comment: Oh, ok !
Thank you so much for this answer. I will try it soon.